# Lexer/Parser for a simple DSL made up of method calls

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler-construction, dsl, lexer

I'm looking to create a lexer and parser for a simple DSL we use with internal tools.  There will be a couple in-built symbols (is this the correct term?) and they'll take anywhere between 1 and 10 arguments.  For example:

```
foo(bar1;bar2)
```

There will also be symbols added at runtime that will always have zero parameter.  Example:

```
testy1()
```

These will be strung together and read from a CSV file.  An assembled line would like like:

```
foo(bar1:bar2)testy1()
```

I've had a hard time finding resources online that easily explain lexing and parsing function calls like these.  Could someone point me in a good direction, or offer advice?

Comment: You may think it is overkill, but I'd download ANTLR and use its tools for this, it would make your job a lot easier once you get past the learning curve.

Comment: See my SO answer on how to build a recursive descent parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769

Comment: I'm unable to have any dependencies on third party libraries, otherwise ANTLR sounds like a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small parser with PegJS that is able to parse simple expressions in function calls. PEGs avoid ambiguity and they work fine for this.

```
Start
  = Expr

/* Expressions */

Expr
  = FuncCall
  / Literal

RestExpr
  = _ ( "," / ":" ) _ e:Expr {
    return e;
  }

/* Function call */

FuncCall
  = func:Ident _ "(" _ x:Expr? xs:RestExpr* _ ")" {
    return {
      type: "FuncCall",
      func: func.value,
      params: x ? [x].concat(xs) : []
    };
  }

/* Literals */

Literal
  = Number
  / Ident

Number
  = val:[0-9]+ {
    return {
      type: "Number",
      value: parseInt(val.join(""))
    };
  }

/* Identifier */

Ident
  = x:IdentStart xs:IdentRest* {
  return {
    type: "Ident",
    value: [x].concat(xs).join("")
  };
}

IdentStart
  = [a-z_]i

IdentRest
  = [a-z0-9_]i
_
  = [ \s\t\r\n]*
```

You can test the parser here: http://pegjs.org/online

An input example is `foo(1, bar(2), baz(3))`, where the output is:

```
{
   "type": "FuncCall",
   "func": "foo",
   "params": [
      {
         "type": "Number",
         "value": 1
      },
      {
         "type": "FuncCall",
         "func": "bar",
         "params": [
            {
               "type": "Number",
               "value": 2
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type": "FuncCall",
         "func": "baz",
         "params": [
            {
               "type": "Number",
               "value": 3
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This clearly isn't the best approach, but I believe `peg-sharp` can do it well with C#: https://code.google.com/p/peg-sharp/.